# What happened to this character creating this phenomenom?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

So, in part 3, we see that Old Joseph tells his grandson, Jotaro Kujo (our protagonist), that

> stands were created by DIO's reawakening.

But in part 4, we see that

> Koichi gets struck by a stand arrow, giving him the stand called Echoes.

These objects were created by

> a meteorite that struck earth https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/Bow_and_Arrow

This caused

> stand arrows to appear, that were given to a young Diavolo

So did they both influence stands, or was it just one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(spoilers for DIO's Diary, Vento Aureo, Phantom Blood, and StarDust Crusaders)

Joseph never said that the stands were created or summoned directly through DIO's awakening, however he did say that ONLY the Joestar bloodline's stands stemmed from him, as he is indirectly a part of it by stealing Jonathan's body, in DIO's Diary: OverHeaven, he explains that when he awakened from his 100 year sleep, he met Enya, who shot him with the arrow, thus giving him, Joseph, Jotaro, and Holly stands. Everything that was said in Vento Aureo and Diamond is Unbreakable, is true, and stands never stemmed directly from DIO or Jonathan.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Helped me understand this wacky timeline better.

Answer (score 1):

It was primarily the arrow actually. Some years after possessing Jonathans body, Dio met an old witch called Enyaba who was in possession of 5 of the stand arrows and using a Stand arrow she helped him awaken his Stand and taught him how to use it [StarDust Crusaders, Jojo part 3]. Consequently this has a large ripple effect on the entire Joestar bloodline and hence most of the Joestars awakened their Stand but that was as a result of Dio's connection through Jonathan's body to his descendants.

Comment: At least in the case of the Joestar bloodline the effect of the arrow was not singular but instead also induced Stands awakening in Jonathans Descendants, not sure if that's a special case of Dios possession tho